# Reload JS programmatically

Tags: ios, react-native

I just want to make my app reload JS bundle when it starts. Is this possible to do programmatically?

Comment: i think that is possible with `native-code`. but i don't know how to implementation that. Maybe [the article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/so-you-want-to-dynamically-update-your-react-native-app-d1d88bf11ede) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the `reload()` method of your `RCTBridge` instance. In our case we have a swift setup something like this:

```
class ReactNativeBridge: NSObject, RCTBridgeDelegate {

    static var shared = ReactNativeBridge()

    private lazy var bridge: RCTBridge = {
        return RCTBridge(delegate: self, launchOptions: nil)
    }()

    func reload() {
        bridge.reload()
    }

    func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! { ... }

}
```